# MySql: Fetch LIMITED results using GROUP BY clause on one table/view

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a view 'view_type' like:

```
type------name------fid

type_a----name1-----12
type_a----name2-----27
type_a----name3-----45
type_a----name4-----43
type_a----name5-----25
type_a----name7-----75
type_a----name6-----15

type_b----bame1-----12
type_b----bame2-----27
type_b----bame3-----45
type_b----bame4-----43
type_b----bame5-----25

type_c----came7-----55
type_c----came6-----25
```

Now i want to fetch results having 'ame' in name field, but only from 'type_a' & 'type_b' and also only 4results from each.

```
type------name------fid

type_a----name1-----12
type_a----name2-----27
type_a----name3-----45
type_a----name4-----43
type_b----bame1-----12
type_b----bame2-----27
type_b----bame3-----45
type_b----bame4-----43
```

In simple words I want to limit results of 'group by' result set.

Don't want to use 'complex sub query' OR 'stored procedure'. Is there any simple query which help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select * from view_type where type = 'type_a' and name regexp 'ame' LIMIT 4
UNION
select * from view_type where type = 'type_b' and name regexp 'ame' LIMIT 4
```